# How to use defined structure WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE in IDL file?

Tags: c++

I want to use the Windows-defined structure in my IDL like:

```
HRESULT SetInputType(const WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE* wavFmt);
```

But I got an error:

> error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification or a storage specifier or a type qualifier near "WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE"

I tried to include `"windows.h"` directly, but it seems not to work?
How should I do if I want add such an API in my IDL files?

Comment: It is tricky, the Microsoft programmer fretted about having the type defined multiple times.  Once from the .h file that MIDL generates and again from an #include in the C++ program.  A workaround is to add two lines in the IDL file: `#include <mmreg.h>`, so MIDL can see the type, and `cpp_quote("include <mmreg.h>")` so the C++ compiler can see the type.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution, it really simple, just using 
`import "Mmreg.h";`
Then this issue is gone.